# How to show that the Poisson equation has its maximum on the boundary?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle, poissons-equation

$$\Delta f=h, x\in\Omega$$
$$f=F, x\in\partial \Omega$$

where $h$ is $C^1$ function s.t. $0\le h$, $0\le h'$ and the domain is in 3D.

then, I want to show that $f$ has its max on boundary. please give me a proof or hint.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Try searching the **maximum principle**. For your particular problem I would focus on the *maximum principle for elliptic PDEs*.

Basically, this principle states that the solution of elliptic (or parabolic) differential equation  reaches its  minimum and maximum on the boundary of the domain.

As a reference I would propose [**this book**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821849743), although you can find plenty of information on maximum principle on the internet.

---

Hope my hint and reference are helpful.